# Home page showing as first link after domain name in SERPs

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets, breadcrumbs

I've just noticed Google is displaying the breadcrumbs as

> domain name > home > page

on internal pages. In my mind it should be:

> domain name > page

without the "Home" displayed. See screen print below:

[image]

This is the code being used on the page:

```html
<ol id="topBreadCrumb" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList" itemscope="">
  <li itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" itemscope="" itemprop="itemListElement"><a href="/" itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemscope="" itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">Home</span></a><meta content="1" itemprop="position"> › </li><li itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" itemscope="" itemprop="itemListElement"><a href="/shop-front-refurbishment/" itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemscope="" itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">Shop Front Spray Painting</span></a><meta content="2" itemprop="position"></li>
</ol>
```

Can anyone make any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Google displays everything correct, according to the code. The `Home` point is generated by `<a href="/" itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemscope="" itemprop="item"><span itemprop="name">Home</span></a>`

If you don't want the Home point in the breadcrumb, your first point should be the next after Home.

Make use of Google's example under https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb